# URI Template variable containing a path?

Tags: java, http, rest, uri, uritemplate

I have a question about URI template variables.

I need to manage an URI with the form:

```
http://netlocation:port/application_path/{variable}
```

the variable can be a path itself, i.e. something like

```
this/variable/is/a/path
```

so that the complete URI appears to be

```
http://netlocation:port/application_path/this/variable/is/a/path
```

how can I manage that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the "+" operator in order to avoid escaping the "/" character:

```
http://netlocation:port/application_path/{+foo}
```

You can try on [URI Template Parser Online](http://www.utilities-online.info/uritemplate/)

Comment: this is the solution to me.

Comment: In case of mapping this request in Spring webflux, use asterisks '*'. Example: @GetMapping("application_path/{*foo}"). Ref.: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webflux/controller/ann-requestmapping.html#webflux-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates

Answer (score 2):

You could use query parameters and just encode the path variable in the standard way:

```
http://netlocation:port/application_path?path=%2Fthis%2Fvariable%2Fisapath
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriTemplate.html ?